# Struggling to rewrite the URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm totally newbie in htaccess and it has been a month since I'm trying to rewrite this one URL but no luck. Tried searching on the internet a lot and tried out the method that worked for others but not working for me unfortunately.

The htaccess rule for my dynamic page works, for example `site/index.php?viewpage=application` shows up as `site/application`

What I'm struggling to do is, I'm trying to rewrite the following url: `site/application?name=abcd&date1-2-3&version=5.0` to `site/application/abcd/1-2-3/5.0`

This is my htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?viewpage=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /application?name=$1&date=$2&version=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !name
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?viewpage=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$  /$1?name=$2&date$3&version=$4 [L]
```

If you want the last line to be limited with application only , replace with this :

```
RewriteRule ^application/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$  /application?name=$1&date$2&version=$3 [L]
```

UPDATE CODE:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !name
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?viewpage=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$  index.php?viewpage=$1?name=$2&date$3&version=$4 [L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm getting an error that the page "/application" was not found on the server when using the query string along. The single dynamic page url works though.

Comment: copy updated code and test it , if not ok let me know